# Java: For-Each loop and references

Tags: java, object, loops, for-loop

I am wondering if the following loop creates a copy of the object, rather than giving me a reference to it. The reason is, because the first example doesn't allocate my array objects, but the second does.

```
MyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6];
for (MyObject o: objects) {

    o = new MyObject();
}

MyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6];
for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

    objects[i] = new MyObject();
}
```

Comment: Is there really a for loop syntax like the first is present in java?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: [for-each loop java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: @ChandraSekhar RanRag is right. However, that is not relevant to the question. Perhaps the OP just rewrote his code, not copy/paste and hence thought in his preferred language.

Comment: @RanRag as per your first comment there should be a colon (:), But my confusion is on the keyword 'in'. From where that comes?

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: Sorry I thought you were wondering about the `for-each` loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java works a little bit different than many other languages. What `o` is in the first example is simply a reference to the object.

When you say `o = new MyObject()`, it creates a new Object of type MyObject and references `o` to that object, whereas before `o` referenced `objects[index]`.

That is, objects[index] itself is just a reference to another object in memory. So in order to set objects[index] to a new MyObject, you need to change where objects[index] points to, which can only be done by using objects[index].

Image: (my terrible paint skills :D)

[image]

Explanation:
This is roughly how Java memory management works. Not exactly, by any means, but roughly. You have objects, which references A1. When you access the objects array, you start from the beginning reference point (A1), and move forward X blocks. For example, referencing index 1 would bring you to B1. B1 then tells you that you're looking for the object at A2. A2 tells you that it has a field located at C2. C2 is an integer, a basic data type. The search is done.

o does not reference A1 or B1, but C1 or C2. When you say `new ...`, it will create a new object and put o there (for example, in slot A3). It will not affect A1 or B1.

Let me know if I can clear things up a little.

Comment: Sure, that makes sence. So in the first example, o is a bit like a C++ pointer, in that it is in itself a variable, and thus it's value is the address of another variable. So when assigning anything to it, the variable, rather than what it is pointing to, is set.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly :D Unlike C++, Java doesn't have much in the way of pointers controls and such. The variables reference places in memory, and `=` re-references them. You can't create a new variable where you referenced. However, you can change this variable. If `o` is already initialized and `o.x` is a field, you can change where `o.x` points, thus reassigning `o.x`.

Answer (score 10):

The **short answer**: yes, there is something like a copy going on.

The **long answer**: The Java foreach loop you posted is syntactic sugar for

```
MyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6];

Iterator<MyObject> it = objects.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   MyObject o = it.next();
   // The previous three lines were from the foreach loop

   // Your code inside the foreach loop
   o = new MyObject();
}
```

As the desugared version shows, setting a reference equal to something inside a foreach loop does not change the contents of the array.

Answer (score 5):

I added a comment into each example to clarify what's going on.

First example:

```
MyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6]; 
for(MyObject o: objects) { 

    // Construct a new object of type MyObject and assign a reference to it into 
    // the iteration variable o. This has no lasting effect, because the foreach
    // loop will automatically assign the next value into the iteration variable
    // in the the next iteration.
    o = new MyObject(); 
}
```

Second example:

```
MyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6]; 
for(int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { 

    // Construct a new object of type MyObject and store a reference to it into the
    // i-th slot in array objects[]:
    objects[i] = new MyObject(); 
}
```

Comment: It will not compile at all, as in is not a keyword in java, You should place a colon(:) there.

Comment: I just copied user's original code before it was edited and I missed it. That said, it doesn't change the point of my answer.

Comment: Whoever -1'd Igor should say why they did it. Negative feedback is no use if you don't offer explanation for improvements. Igor, I suspect you were -1'd due to lack of depth.

Answer (score 3):

The first one isn't allocating your array objects because `foreach` loops iterate over elements in a collection.

When you enter that `foreach` loop you don't have any elements in your collection, it is just an empty array initialized to size 6, so no objects will be added to your array.

Also, note that even if you had elements in the array the `foreach` loop wouldn't assign over top of them:

```
o = new MyObject();
```

basically means assign to `o` a new instance of `MyObject`, but `o` itself isnt part of the array `objects` it is only a temporary container used to iterate over the elements of the array, but in this case, there are none.

Comment: It's not really empty, it just has 6 nulls inside.  Otherwise, good answer.  +1

Comment: empty in the sense that there are no elements of `MyObject` inside of it.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing in different words.

Answer (score 2):

Objects are only "copied" when you explicitly state you want to clone an object (and this object explicitly implements cloning feature).

You seem to confuse references and names.

In the first example, inside a foreach, local `o` variable refers to the area of memory some object from `objects` is stored. When you're doing `o = new MyObject()`, a new MyObject is initialized in some other area of memory, and then `o` reference is rewritten to point on this new area of memory.

In the second example, by writing `objects[i] = new MyObject()`, you're saying that `objects[i]` reference should be rewritten, not some local `o` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I want to mentioned is that non zero length arrays are always mutable.And inside the foreach loop

```
for(MyObject o in objects)
```

what it does is in each iteration it works as following.

```
o = objects[0] // first iteration 
o = objects[1] // 2nd iteration
```

But in your case you assign another object to the reference o. Not to the objects in the array.Its simply like following.

```
ObjeMyObject objects[] = new MyObject[6];
 MyObject o = Object[0];
 0 = new MyObject();
```

But your original objects[0] still point to a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you use "new" operator JVM will create a new instance and it will be assigned to the Left hand side operand of assignment operator.
it doesn't matter on for each loop or for loop. 
In for each loop 
for(MyObject O : Object)
O will be created once only that will be of MyObject it will not be instantiated and the values from the Object array will be keep copying in O 
like

```
O = Object[0]
O = Object[1]
O = Object[2]
O = Object[3]
O = Object[4]
O = Object[5]
```

We do not need to tack care of increasing the counter, thats the beauty of for Each loop.