# Iterate through List or get Object by index from List?

Tags: java, bukkit

Ok, so for example I have class Arena and added them to list and I need to get Arena by one parameter. It is more efficient to iterate through every object or get them from list ? Which way is more efficient?

```
public Arena getArena(String param) {
    List<Arena> arenas = ...;
    for(Arena arena : arenas) {
        if(arena.getParameter().equals(param)) return arena;
    }
}
```

OR

```
public Arena getArena(String param) {
    List<Arena> arenas = ...;
    for(int i = 0; i < arenas.size(); i++) {
        if(arenas.get(i).getParameter().equals(param)) return arenas.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether you notice it, but in the second snippet, you iterate through every object as well. so ... I don't see why any should be more efficiënt. The second one is safer if the id is unique and the param not necessarily, but ...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305632/java-for-each-loop-and-references

Comment: @Ascalonian I think they are similar in method, but benR wouldn't have been able to find it based on title of questions.

Comment: @NealC - Was just a simple Google search for "Java Object loop" and that was the first result. It helps a lot (and prevents downvotes and closings) to do some good searches before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the List implementation you are using has random access (for example ArrayList) or not (for example LinkedList).

If it doesn't have random access, the second option would be less efficient, since arenas.get(i) would require iterating from the start (or from the end) of the list to the requested index.

If it's a random access list, both options would have similar running times, but the first one looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

The best way in my opinion is if you se `HashMap` since you can get element at O(1).
But you need to add areas to hash map instead of list.

See this example:

```
public Arena getArena(String param) {
    HashMap<String, Arena> arenasHash = ...;
    return arenasHash.get(param);
}
```

Comment: Note that HashMap does not preserve the order of entries in which they are added. So, in case we want the first Arena having the parameter param, we should use a LinkedHashMap or ImmutableMap instead as they preserve order.